# Mirror podcast feed locally

Tags: rss, debian, podcast

I have a relatively old Android phone that I use only for podcast listening. I'm subscribed to a few podcasts, but since the wireless around the house is not so great, the wifi connection of the phone gets interrupted from time to time while downloading new episodes (10 min per episode). Somehow this causes the episodes to be sometimes corrupted, so I have to re-download when at home again or sometimes even error check the SD card.

Since I have a Debian server running locally, I am looking for a way to mirror the podcast rss feeds locally. So that my podcatcher on the phone is subscribed to local feeds, which will be much faster and the chances are smaller that the connection is interrupted during download.

The closest I got is this perl library: [MP3::PodcastFetch](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/MP3-PodcastFetch-1.05/lib/MP3/PodcastFetch.pm)

Is there anything for Debian in the repositories that can do this?

- Check subscribed feed regularly (ie. cron)
- Download new episodes
- Host a local rss feed pointing to the local copies of the podcast

Answer (score 0):

As the podcast is delivered via HTTP you can use a caching HTTP proxy on the local debian box. You might have a look at `squid3` and [this tutorial](http://funnybutnot.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/setting-up-a-squid-caching-proxy/)